# When is the next day?

Tags: hearthstone

In hearthstone, you receive one quest per day, barring unique quests. What I'm wondering is when exactly does a new day start? I assume it's at a specific global time, so I'm looking for a time in GMT or UTC.

I did find out you need to exit the game and come back to receive new quests, but I'm hoping someone actually knows when i have to do that.

Comment: While I'm not sure of the exact time, you can be sure that it's a PST time not a GMT or UTC one.  Nearly all of their patches, server restarts, or daily changes are based on their home time zone which is PST.

Comment: Well, any PST time can be converted to GMT or UTC. It's just that those 2 are commonly known any most people know their time difference to them. Unlike PST, I would have to look that up...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Daily quests are reset at [3 AM server time](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Quest), which will differ based on your currently set [Battle.net region](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/global-play), and which specific server you connect to: the numbers below may vary.

- For the North American region, servers are typically on PST (-7 GMT), which means that currently (as the US is in daylight savings time) it will reset at 10 AM GMT.
- For the European region, servers are typically on CET (+1 GMT), which means that they will reset at 2 AM GMT.
- For the Asian region, servers are typically on KST (+9 GMT), which means that they will reset at 6 PM GMT.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm on GMT+1, and when I logged on shortly after 9AM yesterday, I already had the new daily quest. Might be related to the maintenance that took place at 12AM in my time zone that night, though. Or they reset them based on location...

Comment: @scenia Unfortunately, beyond North America, I can't say that I really know where the hearthstone servers are based, although I do know they maintain some EU servers as well.  Is it possible you're connecting to them, instead?

Comment: @scenia As a followup to that, I've turned up [some](http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1139498-Blizzard-s-Physical-Server-Locations-where-are-they-all) (admittedly anecdotal) evidence that the EU servers are all maintianed in GMT+1 as well - things may be resetting at 3 AM on the dot where you are.

Comment: That sounds realistic. I guess I'm connecting to the EU servers since the region I set in the Battle.net client is Europe. There was also a notice that changing my region would reset all kinds of stuff, different physical servers are probably the reason for this. You should include that additional info in your answer :)

Comment: @scenia Done and done!